# Changing CSS in dynamically generated HTML

Tags: html, css, generated

How can I get access and change CSS like the font color in completely dynamically generated HTML out of XML, if I cannot use an ID as I do not know in advance how many of the same HTML-tags will be generated and which of two different (red/green) colors it will need? (I am new here and very new in JS)

Data will be generated and collected on the server. I get them back and sort them in a "fieldset" and further more in a "collapsible". Data "var a, b and c" come together in one line (fieldset) and should be in a specific font color. So for "var d" there will be a "xx" or "yy" coming back from XML for this font color and be saved in "var d" and therefore the font color should be "red" or "green".

Part of my script in short:

```
function addPart(currentIndex,currentPart)
{
    var a = $(currentPart).find("a").text();
    var b = $(currentPart).find("b").text();
    var c = $(currentPart).find("c").text();        
    var d = $(currentPart).find("d").text();
    if(d === "xx") {
        $("div.productColor").css({"color":"green"});
    } else {
        $("div.productColor").css({"color":"red"});
    };

    $("#shoppingTableDiv").append (
        "<div data-role='collapsible'>"

            + "<h3>"
                + "<div class='productColor'>"
                        + "<fieldset class='ui-grid-b'>"
                            + "<div class='ui-block-a'>" 
                            + a
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<div class='ui-block-b'>" 
                            + b
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<div class='ui-block-c'>" 
                            + c
                            + "</div>"
                        + "</fieldset>"
                + "</div>"
            + "</h3>"
          + "</div>");

    $('#shoppingTableDiv').collapsibleset('refresh');                

}
```

Comment: You could generate IDs, using a counter to keep them unique...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand how you want to color your results, but I think you can use your `fieldset` classes.

For example:

```
.ui-grid-b div { color: red; }
.ui-grid-c div { color: green; }
```

If you don't know how many fieldsets you're going to have and you can't use the fieldset classes you showed in your code example, you might find the [`nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) selector useful.

Maybe something like this:

```
fieldset:nth-child(2n) div { color: red; }
fieldset:nth-child(2n+1) div { color: green; }
```